# 'QObject& QObject::operator=(const QObject&)' is private

Tags: c++, qt, migration, copy-constructor

Migrating a project from Qt4 to Qt5 I get this error, I have researched and apparently you cant make a copy constructor of a derived class from QObject (which is incredible because this code isnt mine and its supposed to compile in a previous version). The copy constructor doesnt really copy any of the QObject values, and I dont know whats wrong with the QList thingy.

```
In file included from ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtGui/qwindowdefs.h:45:0,
                 from ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include\QtWidgets/qwidget.h:45,
                 from ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include\QtWidgets/QWidget:1,
                 from ..\marssies\wavingwidget.h:4,
                 from ..\marssies\wavingwidget.cpp:1:
..\marssies\graphicsprimitive.h: In instantiation of 'void QList<T>::node_construct(QList<T>::Node*, const T&) [with T = SIZArrow]':
..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qlist.h:515:32:   required from 'void QList<T>::append(const T&) [with T = SIZArrow]'
..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qlist.h:301:49:   required from 'void QList<T>::push_back(const T&) [with T = SIZArrow]'
..\marssies\wavingwidget.cpp:345:23:   required from here
In file included from ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtGui/qwindowdefs.h:45:0,
                     from ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include\QtWidgets/qwidget.h:45,
                     from ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include\QtWidgets/QWidget:1,
                     from ..\marssies\wavingwidget.h:4,
                     from ..\marssies\wavingwidget.cpp:1:
    ..\marssies\graphicsprimitive.h: In instantiation of 'void QList<T>::node_construct(QList<T>::Node*, const T&) [with T = SIZPolygon]':
    ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qlist.h:515:32:   required from 'void QList<T>::append(const T&) [with T = SIZPolygon]'
    ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qlist.h:301:49:   required from 'void QList<T>::push_back(const T&) [with T = SIZPolygon]'
    ..\marssies\wavingwidget.cpp:330:24:   required from here
    ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qglobal.h:981:12: error: 'QObject& QObject::operator=(const QObject&)' is private
         Class &operator=(const Class &) Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE;
                ^
    ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qobject.h:465:5: note: in expansion of macro 'Q_DISABLE_COPY'
         Q_DISABLE_COPY(QObject)
         ^
    In file included from ..\marssies\wavingwidget.h:10:0,
                     from ..\marssies\wavingwidget.cpp:1:
    ..\marssies\graphicsprimitive.h:50:7: error: within this context
     class GraphicsPrimitive : public QObject {
           ^
    In file included from ..\marssies\wavingwidget.h:13:0,
                     from ..\marssies\wavingwidget.cpp:1:
    ..\marssies\polygon.h:6:7: note: synthesized method 'GraphicsPrimitive& GraphicsPrimitive::operator=(const GraphicsPrimitive&)' first required here 
     class SIZPolygon : public GraphicsPrimitive {
           ^
    In file included from ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qobject.h:51:0,
                     from ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include\QtWidgets/qwidget.h:46,
                     from ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include\QtWidgets/QWidget:1,
                     from ..\marssies\wavingwidget.h:4,
                     from ..\marssies\wavingwidget.cpp:1:
    ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qlist.h:372:35: note: synthesized method 'SIZPolygon& SIZPolygon::operator=(const SIZPolygon&)' first required here 
         else *reinterpret_cast<T*>(n) = t;
                                       ^
```

Part of wavingwidget.cpp

```
SIZPolygon d;
/* ...more code...*/
d.setData(TRIANGLE_VERTEX_FIRST, w1Data.pointNumber);
d.setData(TRIANGLE_VERTEX_SECOND, w2Data.pointNumber);
d.setData(TRIANGLE_VERTEX_THIRD, w3Data.pointNumber);
d.setData(POLYGON_WAVEHEIGHT, waveAltVal);

polygons.push_back(d); //wavingwidget.cpp:330:24

double waveComputedDir = (w1Data.waveDirection + w2Data.waveDirection + w3Data.waveDirection) / 3.0;
```

Part of graphicsprimitive.h

```
class GraphicsPrimitive : public QObject { //graphicsprimitive.h:50:7

    Q_OBJECT
friend class PainterBar;

public:
    GraphicsPrimitive(void);
    GraphicsPrimitive(const GraphicsPrimitive&);
    ~GraphicsPrimitive(void);
```

Part of polygon.h

```
class SIZPolygon : public GraphicsPrimitive { //polygon.h:6:7

public:
    SIZPolygon();
    ~SIZPolygon(void);
    void draw(QPainter*);
    void addPoint(double, double, int);
    bool containsScreen(int, int);
    bool containsGeo(double, double);
    QList<QPair<int, int> > getCenterPoints();
    QPair<double, double> getGeoCenterPoint();
    bool isOverNode(int, int, int*);
    void movePoint(int, int, int);
    void move(int, int);
    void toXML(QDomElement*, QDomDocument*);
    int containsSegment(int, int);

private:
    void countCOFMA(double*, double, double, double, double);
};
```

As you can see I pass the QObject by constant reference, so in fact I am not sure whats wrong with the code, its probably the QList thing but I dont see how. I have seen similar questions but didnt find anything that could help me.
I will be happy just knowing which part is failing/what to look for, that way I can search better for a solution


EDIT


I did what @ratchetfreak told me, and managed to solve some errors but it still says that its private:

```
..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qglobal.h:981:12: error: 'QObject& QObject::operator=(const QObject&)' is private
     Class &operator=(const Class &) Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE;
            ^
..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qobject.h:465:5: note: in expansion of macro 'Q_DISABLE_COPY'
     Q_DISABLE_COPY(QObject)
     ^
In file included from ..\marssies\wavingwidget.h:10:0,
                 from ..\marssies\wavingwidget.cpp:1:
..\marssies\graphicsprimitive.h:50:7: error: within this context
 class GraphicsPrimitive : public QObject {
       ^
In file included from ..\marssies\wavingwidget.h:11:0,
                 from ..\marssies\wavingwidget.cpp:1:
..\marssies\arrow.h:7:7: note: synthesized method 'GraphicsPrimitive& GraphicsPrimitive::operator=(const GraphicsPrimitive&)' first required here 
 class SIZArrow : public GraphicsPrimitive
       ^
In file included from ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qobject.h:51:0,
                 from ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include\QtWidgets/qwidget.h:46,
                 from ..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include\QtWidgets/QWidget:1,
                 from ..\marssies\wavingwidget.h:4,
                 from ..\marssies\wavingwidget.cpp:1:
..\..\..\..\..\Qt5\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qlist.h:372:35: note: synthesized method 'SIZArrow& SIZArrow::operator=(const SIZArrow&)' first required here 
     else *reinterpret_cast<T*>(n) = t;
```

Comment: what is `d` in `polygons.push_back(d);`? the parameter that is passed in?

Comment: @ratchetfreak right! Sorry for not mentioning it, the declaration is SIZPolygon d;, I already modified the post, thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

QObjects are not copyable and meant to be referenced by pointer only; so the declaration of `QList<SIZPolygon>` (as I see in your error message) would have caused problems sooner or later.

Either remove the inheritance from QObject for GraphicsPrimitive if it is not really needed

or change it to `QList<SIZPolygon*>` and reparent as needed

```
SIZPolygon* d = new SIZPolygon();
d->setParent(this);
//convention is to add a QObject parent=0 to the constructor but this works as well
```

and when you need to delete it you call `d->deleteLater()` on it.

Comment: sadly it is needed, so I tried what you said, but I a mstill getting the same error, check the edits

Comment: @VíctorAsdasd that looks to be a similar error in another place, double check that you always pass QObjects by pointer

Comment: Hey, I am compiling now after parsing a crazy amount of code. It was a similar error, just a few lines under the first one, which means that it got solved, thankyou very much!. Also, do you know whats the difference between QList<Type> and QList<Type*>?

Comment: @VíctorAsdasd the first holds a copy of the object the other a pointer to the object